# Customize Message Box WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

[image]

Is there a way to add an icon before title in message box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF : why doesnt messagebox have icon on titlebar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212188/wpf-why-doesnt-messagebox-have-icon-on-titlebar)

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you can override this behavior of MessageBox. Use some custom message box or implement your own MessageBoxForm and add your custom settings to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom MessageBox.
Here is a good example: 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WPF-Messagebox-4a038c72